# How to enter/start cell edit mode from add-in code in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: c#, interop, vsto, excel-2010, excel-interop

Is there any way to make Excel 2010 enter cell-edit mode for selected cells from code of add-in that is written in C# with Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0 and VSTO 4.0 (or in other versions of Excel and add-in development tools - except for sending *key press* events)?

Could you please provide references to documentation of classes and methods that allow to switch Excel 2010 into cell edit mode from code of add-on or reference to documentation which explicitly tells that there is no API in VSTO for switching Excel to *Edit mode*.

Comment: Why do you need to be in edit mode and why can't you use `SendKeys`?

Comment: @Brad I need to be in edit-mode to implement item of drop-down list (validation that allows selecting cell value from drop-down) for cell which: 1) removes validation-constraint from cell, 2) prompts user to enter new value for cell (with keyboard - here need to enter edit-mode to trigger *cell changed* event to perform following item) and then 3) sets new validation-constraint (with entered value appended). Do not want to use `SendKeys` as it is not reliable and can send keys to another UI element or to another window at all.

Comment: However terrible it is in many other situations here's where `Cells().Select` can come in handy. It will ensure that your cell of interest is the selected cell. you can even set the focus to Excel so you know when you send `F2` it is going to the right program with `AppActivate Application.Caption`. It seems like there is not another way to enter edit moode, from what I've seen, than to press `F2`